# Perl : First Saturday of the month and call function

Tags: perl

Friends.. 
In Perl how do we check if it's first Saturday of the month and if it's true call another function..

I search on internet but all option I could found was for ksh scripting..

```
--PERL
use warning;
use strict;

IF first_saturday = TRUE
  THEN
     msg "It's First Saturday"
     call delete()
  ELSE
     msg "Not First Saturday
END IF
```

thanks...

Comment: [`perldoc -f localtime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#localtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) which has been included since Perl 5.10 as a standard module. Unfortunately, it doesn't include a *week of month* method. However, [Date::Handler](http://search.cpan.org/~bbeausej/Date-Handler-1.2/Handler.pod) does.

It's a nice clean interface, and makes it obvious what you're looking for. Too bad it's not a standard Perl module, so you have to install it from CPAN.

```
use Date::Handler;

....

my $date = Date::Handler->new($time);  #Time is std Unix # of seconds since 01/01/1970

# Is it the sixth day of the week (Mon = 1) and the first week of the month?
if ( $date->WeekDay == 6 and $date->WeekOfMonth == 1 ) {
    print "It's the first Saturday of the month!\n";
}
```

OR...

```
my $date = Date::Handler->new($time);

# Is it the first Saturday of the month?
if ( $date->WeekDayName eq "Saturday" and $date->WeekOfMonth == 1 ) {
    print "It's the first Saturday of the month!\n";
}
```

You can't make it easier to see exactly what your code is doing than this.

Comment: thanks for the easy code but unfortunately I can't use Date:Handler.. I have perl vesion-5.8.2   when I tried using Date:Handler it gave me error "Can't locate object method"  any way doing this without using new handler?

Comment: You can install Date::Handler, it works on 5.8: http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/D/Date-Handler.html#Date-Handler-1.2

Comment: unfortunately I don't have permission to install and it will take ages to get approval from management.. :(

Comment: @Khallas301 If you have 5.8.2, and cannot install CPAN modules, you're pretty much stuck with [Scroog1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17951761/368630)'s answer. Even the `Time::Piece` module isn't included in Perl before 5.10.

Comment: @DavidW. it will be great, if you include `cpan` introduction to OP ;)

Comment: thank you all for this wonderfull tips.. it really helped... I will try to install and use other ideas as @DavidW and others suggested...

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this (using @mob's suggestion of localtime):

```
sub is_first_saturday {
    my @time_elements = localtime(time);
    my $day_of_week = $time_elements[6];
    my $day_of_month = $time_elements[3];
    return $day_of_week == 6 && $day_of_month < 8;
}
```

You probably want to pass the date into the function, rather than assuming today though.

Comment: thanks @Scroog1 so function will check for first Satuday and I can use it in if..else condition or do I need to check function for true/false?

Comment: @Khallas301 This function will return _true_ if it is the first Saturday and _false_ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try about [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.40/lib/Date/Manip/Examples.pod) module.

```
use strict;
use Date::Manip;

$main::TZ= 'GMT';
print UnixDate(ParseDate("first Saturday in July 2013"),"First Saturday of the month is %B %E, %Y.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use DateTime;

# day: 1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday
# nth: 1 = 1st time a day appears, ..., 5 = last time a day appears in a month
sub is_nth_day_of_month {
    my ( $nth, $day ) = @_;

    my $now = DateTime->now;

    return $now->day_of_week == $day && $now->weekday_of_month == $nth;
}

print is_nth_day_of_month(1, 6) ? "Yes\n" :  "No\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $day  = substr (`date`,0,3);
my $date = substr(`date`,8,2) ;
if($day =~/Wed/ and $date <= 7){
   print "Hey today is first Saturday\n";
}
```